# ConcurrentSkipList? That is, not a ConcurrentSkipListSet

Tags: java, concurrency, skip-lists

I need a very fast (insert, remove, contains) highly concurrent **list** that can be sorted using a comparator/comparable.

The existing ConcurrentSkipListSet would be ideal, if it was a list and not a set.  I need to insert multiple items which are equal into the data structure.

I'm currently thinking of using a LinkedDeque if I can't find anything better, but that structure is considerably slower than a skiplist at high contention.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: What I actually need, bare minimum, is something that is sorted using compareTo, can insert concurrently and can remove/get items using object identity. All other concurrent requirements mentioned in comments still apply.

Comment: What do you mean with "very fast"? I've seen people winning programming performance contests with bubble-sort written in ASM. Do you mean constant-time, or linear time, compared to the number of elements in the list?

Comment: Do you know an estimate for the ratio of the number of changes to the list and the number of read accesses?

Comment: If you have a highly contented sort list, it sounds like you have a design issue.  Most likely there is a way to restructure your problem so this is not the case.

Comment: @Gray Skiplists should have O(logN) random access because you don't traverse the bottom-layer list---you *skip* into it at the proper spot.

Comment: I know how skip lists work @Marko.  I was just pointing out that if he needs a list because of iteration or something, skip lists will work as wel.  I've pulled by comment into an answer and I'll flesh out that point.

Comment: @Gray I was pretty sure you knew all about them :) but the comment seemed to imply a different thing.

Comment: I actually used to be on the wikipedia page as one of the early implementations of SkipLists in source because I put it in my memory debugging dmalloc library way, way back when.  :-)

Comment: By very fast I mean faster than LinkedBlockingQueue at high contention on multiprocessor machines with at least 20 cores. Essentially something that uses CAS internally instead of synchronizing on everything (or at the very least using striped locks).


The usage case is that I need to keep track of timeouts, and the fastest way I've found is a ConcurrentSkipListSet with timeout used as the sorting key, and then another thread iterating on the set that sleeps until the next timeout.. unfortunately it stops working when two objects have the same timeout value.

Comment: Argh... I just realized I had a brain fart. What I actually need is a sorted list that I can iterate over. That can insert things anywhere and remove based on the object identity, not based on compareTo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The existing ConcurrentSkipListSet would be ideal, if it was a list and not a set.

So the [SkipList data-structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) at it's core is a linked list.  If you are worried about order and the ability to traverse it easily and in order, the SkipList will work very well for that as well.  It is also a probabilistic  alternative to a balanced tree which is why it can also be a `Set` or a `Map`.  The data structure in memory looks something like the following:

[image]

To quote from the Javadocs:

> This class implements a concurrent variant of SkipLists providing expected average log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations and their variants. Insertion, removal, update, and access operations safely execute concurrently by multiple threads. Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the map at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, and may proceed concurrently with other operations. Ascending key ordered views and their iterators are faster than descending ones.

If you explain more about what features you want from `List`, I can answer better whether `ConcurrentSkipListSet` will be able to work.

---

**Edit:**

Ah, I see.  After some back and forth in the comment, it seems like you need to be able to stick two objects that are equivalent into the `Set` which isn't possible.  What we worked out is to never have `compareTo(...)` return 0.  It's a bit of a hack but using `AtomicLong` to generate a unique number for each object, you can then compare those numbers whenever the real comparison field (in this case a numerical timeout value) is equal.  This will allow objects with the same field to be inserted into the `Set` and kept in the proper order based on the field.

Comment: It wont work because its a set, which does not allow duplicate values, or more accurately, if compareTo() == 0 then it overwrites the first object on the second insert

Comment: Ah I see.  Are you ever looking up the item with .equals?  If not and you are just inserting and then iterating through the list, you could change the `compareTo()` to never return 0 although it's a hack @MarcB.

Comment: I can do the lookup on object identity or equals if needed. Considered the hack, just not sure what I'd do instead... I'm fairly sure that an if( compareTo == 0) then return -1; would break something inside the set?

Comment: Bit of a hack @MarcB but how about an `AtomicLong` which generates a unit number per the object your are sticking in the queue.  Then if compareTo == 0, compare those numbers?

Comment: Oh and yes, if you return -1 if two objects had the same timeout then it would break something because then A < B and B < A.

Comment: That works... I think. If you edit answer to include it i'll accept it :)

Comment: Done @MarcB.  I think that summarizes things.

Comment: late to the party, but could this work? if (mightReturnZero) { return hashCode() - another.hashCode(); } else return theNonZeroValue;

Comment: (..considering they actually have different hash codes. But comparator returns the same value, same due time for example)

Comment: Adding AtomicLong (get increase and set) cause loosing "Concurrent structure" performance. Atomic makes a single point but Concurrent stuctures uses much much better parallelizm

Comment: Do you see any other solution around the OP's issue @TuğrulKarakaya?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Set with a comparator that never returns 0.

```
private Set<Obj> entities = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>((o1, o2) -> {
      if (o1.equals(o2)) {
         // Return -1 or 1 - decide where you want to place an object when it's equals to another one
         return -1;
      }
      // Implement the sorting order below
      if (o1.getTimestamp() < o2.getTimestamp()) {
         return -1;
      }
      if (o1.getTimestamp() > o2.getTimestamp()) {
         return 1;
      }

      return -1;
   })
```

;

Comment: This will produce an unstable sort.